# Passing BindingList<CustomObject> to button_Click method on second form

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, pass-by-reference, bindinglist

I have to forms.

First has datagridview with `BindingList<CustomObject>` as `DataSource`.

Second should add/remove/update `DataSource` from the first form.

How can I do this? Modifying etc is happening in `button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` on secondform. I could pass `BindignList<>` by `ref` to `SecondForms()` constructor, but I can't pass it further to `button_Click()`

Comment: Are the forms created separately or does form1 create form2

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes, SecondForm is creating in FirstForm

Comment: Did you try creating an event in form2 that form1 will subscribe to?

Comment: @LewsTherin Can you provide simple example how do you imagine this situation?

Comment: Saint look at my answer. With little code I can't help much.

Comment: @LewsTherin Especially in SecondForm. How to work on my BindingList<> (I suppose I should pass it in CustomEventArgs) and work on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an event in form2 that form1 will subscribe to. Keeping things sort of separate. 
I don't know how you have structured Form1 and Form2 so I will just give an example.

```
class Form2 : Something
{
  public event NotifySubscriberEventHandler NotifySubscriberEvent ;
   public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var handler = NotifySubscriberEvent ;
      if( handler != null)
       {
          handler(this,EventArgs.Empty) ;
       } 

   } 
} 

class Form1 
{
   public BindingList<T> MyBindingList {get;set;} //
   public void CreateForm2()
   {
       Form2 form2 = new Form2() ; 
       form2.NotifySubscriberEvent += OnButtonClicked;

   }
   public void OnButtonClicked(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
     //Do Something when notified
      MyBindingList.Add(...)
   }
}
```

You will have to create a NotifySubsubscriberEventHandler delegate. 
Here:
http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html#Simple%20Event

But you already say you are passing BindingList into a constructor I assume like this:

```
public class Form2
{
  private BindingList<T> bindingList ;
  public Form2(BindingList<T> bindingList)
  {
       this.bindingList = bindingList ;
  }

   public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   // Do     bindingList.Add() or whatever

   } 
}
```

Does the above not work? ^^

Comment: But how can I get in Form1 the BindingList<T> that was changed in Form2?

Comment: You wouldn't have to change it in Form2. 
If BindingList<T> is a member of Form1, you already have access to it in the OnButtonClicked method.. I will update my answer to reflect what I mean

Comment: If I understand you correctly yes. So Form2 doesn't know anything about BindingList been changed. All it says is "notify all subscribers to do whatever they want to do. What the subscribers do I have no freaking idea and I don't care."

Comment: It's not exactly what I want, but basically it will be helpful. Thanx